# The difference b/w asynchronous networking and synchronous networking on a secondary thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, networking

I am reading the app document "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html" who puts forward two solutions for avoiding running network on main thread:

1.**asynchronous networking** — The best solution to this problem is to run your networking code asynchronously. Asynchronous networking code has a number of advantages, not least of which is that it lets you access the network safely without having to worry about threads.

2.**synchronous networking on a secondary thread** — If it's prohibitively difficult to run your networking code asynchronously (perhaps you're working with a large portable code base that assumes synchronous networking), you can avoid the watchdog by running your synchronous code on a secondary thread.

I have several questions here:

1. Does "asynchronous networking" means the system will automately create secondary thread to run network request and "synchronous networking on a secondary thread" means creating secondary thread by yourself explictly.
2. I can not figure out the situation "you're working with a large portable code base that assumes synchronous networking", can you show me an example?
3. If 1 is not right, what is the difference in essence?

Thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

As to #1 - yes, you are correct.

As to #2 - an example would be working with a peripheral device. I once worked on an app that communicated with a kind of a ticket machine. Printing a single ticket required sending about 20-30 instructions over the network, in sequence and new instructions could be send only after confirmation came back from the machine. It was easier for me/looked cleaner when I had it all in a single method which got run on a second thread.